# FFplay - Seek to previous key frame

Tags: ffmpeg

Is it possible to have FFplay seek from current position to the position of the previous I-Frame?

I'm trying to find a way to do this as fast as possible without generating a full FFprobe `-show_frames` report to identify where the desired position is.

Comment: Not quite an answer but might be close enough: you can avoid a full probe by using the `-read_intervals` [option](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html). Eg *"Read only 42 packets after seeking to position 01:23: `-read_intervals 01:23%+#42`"*

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Unfortunately, most of the files I am dealing with are H264 bitstreams that do not have PTS information.  It looks like the `-read_intervals` option only accepts inputs related to time - which I unfortunately don't have.  Any other thoughts?  Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, tricky. Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with `ffplay` itself- if no answer here presents itself; you might have better luck on the [`ffmpeg-user` mailing list](https://www.ffmpeg.org/contact.html#MailingLists).

Answer (score 0):

A video can only start decoding on an I-Frame, so the earliest you can start watching your video from the current position is the I-Frame you want.

The application seems a bit hazy but if you're trying to get a human to do some sort of QA over a single intra-frame period then this is how I would go about it.

Comment: I understand this.  What I'm trying to do is seek from current position to the position of the preceding I-frame.  We deal with a lot of variable GOP files, and without a full index (which can take a long time to generate) knowing the position of the I-frame can be cumbersome.    I was hoping there would be an automated way within FFplay to do the seek.